# Hibernate can not save/update/remove an object

Tags: hibernate, hibernate3

I have a very big problem with Hibernate.
When I try to Update or Save an element in a table, I have this error:

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

This error is produced when I call my DAO service:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.saveOrUpdate(object);
session.flush();
```

When I debug, after flush() the error is generated.

Here the Key of the table:

```
@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "sysDocId", column = @Column(name = "SYS_DOC_ID", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "sysDataFile", column = @Column(name = "SYS_DATA_FILE", nullable = false)) })
public RelDocFileId getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

This would mean that Hibernate can't find this record in the database, UPDATE statement returns a result: 0 rows were affected by that update.

Hibernate figures out that what you're going to update does not exist anymore which means that you're saving an outdated data.

You should either not allow this situation or handle this exception appropriately, closing the session and saying to user 'Hey, you see an outdated data, it doesn't exist anymore'.

Comment: Even in insert or remove I have this problem

Comment: On delete it's the same situation as I've described - it tries to delete and there is nothing to delete. On inserts.. do you have an entity cascadely inserted? Hibernate would use saveOrUpdate for these purposes.. Also do you have `assigned` strategy of ID generation? Hibernate might not recognize whether the entity is new or it was persisted already if you specify ID on your own. The mapping and the way how you insert/delete/update would be helpful.